# Writing RSA PrivateKey PEM to file in golang

Tags: go, openssl

I'm using [spacemonkeygo's openssl library](https://godoc.org/github.com/spacemonkeygo/openssl) to generate an RSA PrivateKey - the library also offers ways to load a private key from a PEM, but I can't figure out how to turn the private key into an encrypted PEM block - anyone got any ideas?

```
import "github.com/spacemonkeygo/openssl"

// Generate a private key
privateKey, _ := openssl.GenerateRSAKey(2048)

password := "an encryption password"
// Create an encrypted PEM block from the private key?
pem := ???

// Load the PEM file
loadedPrivateKey, _ := openssl.LoadPrivateKeyFromPEMWidthPassword(pem, password)

privateKey == loadedPrivateKey
```

Comment: What format is the key in after ***`privateKey := openssl.GenerateRSAKey(2048)`***? It may be in PEM already. If not, then its ASN.1/DER. In this case, you can use the command line to convert it if that's an option to you.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can achieve this with x509.EncryptPEMBlock.

If your key is surrounded by `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` post- and prefixes you might have to remove them before encryption.